# ASP Net identity - Добавление пользователя при создании БД

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-identity-3

Использую стандартный ASP Net identity для работы с пользователями.
Имеется стандартный класс IdentityModels.cs:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Обратите внимание, что authenticationType должен совпадать с типом, определенным в CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Здесь добавьте утверждения пользователя
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Подскажите, где и как сделать добавление первоначального пользователя при создании БД?!

Comment: справку посмотрите (старая, но суть должна быть ясна): https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в домашем проекте использую asp.net core 2.2, на Startup запускаю следующее

```
private async Task CheckAdminUser(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
{
    const string adminRole = RoleConstants.Administrator;

    if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(adminRole))
    {
        var role = new ApplicationRole { Name = adminRole };
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
    }

    var admin = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("admin");
    if (admin == null)
    {
        var adminModel = new ApplicationUser 
        { 
            UserName = "admin", 
            Password = "123", 
            LastName = "admin", 
            FirstName = "admin", 
            Email = "admin@admin.sample" 
        };
        await userManager.CreateAsync(adminModel, adminModel.Password);
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminModel, adminRole);
    }
}
```

Топорно, но у меня всегда есть юзер по умолчанию, пароль при первом запуске конечно меняется. Но есть и минусы - юзер admin всегда должен существовать, как и роль администратора. Если их удалить, то на следущем перезапуске сервиса они добавятся. 
Моим требованиям это идеально подходило.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне это тоже подходит!