# Инициализация БД с готовыми значениями при Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

Есть проект ASP.NET MVC Core. В проекте используется БД MS SQL Server.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при первичном развёртывании в БД добавлялись некоторые первоначальные данные.

- Роли и пользователи (используется стандартный Identity);
- Некоторые тестовые данные для своих таблиц.

Пробую делать через миграции, но ничего не выходит. В том числе потому, что все мои "находки" из сети устарели и относятся хорошо если к EF 6.

Как такое правильно реализовать?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: Со "своими" таблицами теперь понятно. Спасибо! А, с Identity что делать?

Comment: Я в своем домашнем проекте просто [проверяю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1032403/179763) наличие юзера при старте руками, если его нет, то добавляю с захардкоденным паролем.